# Twisted DTLS connection

Tags: python, twisted, m2crypto, pyopenssl

How to implement dtls protocol using twisted with m2crypto (or pyopenssl)?

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there's an update on this? I've looked around and DTLS seems to have been introduced somewhere in pyOpenssl-1.1 or something (I'm tired so the version may be incorrect). However there's no actual documentation I could find on that really. So I was just wondering whether there is actual DTLS support in pyOpenSSL now, or would one still need to extend the library?

Comment: There's a patch for pyOpenSSL which implements DTLS.  It has not yet been incorporated into a release, though.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/454737

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither pyOpenSSL nor M2Crypto exposes OpenSSL's DTLS features (as far as I know).  So, the first step would be to extend one of these libraries to support it.  After that, you could extend Twisted to use the new features you just added to the underlying SSL library.

Comment: I hope to find the solution "out-of-box" :)

Comment: Considering Mr. Calderone is one of the main Twisted devs, if he's recommending this to you, it means there is no such solution available "out-of-box". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

gnutls in version 3.2 now supports DTLS, for some cffi wrappers you might want to look at https://github.com/apexo/pgdtls